# How to add a select field for non-related models in the form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, activerecord

I have three models. Article, Category and Subcategory.

Relations:

```
Article belongs_to :subcategory
Subcategory has_many :articles
Subcategory belongs_to :category
Category has_many :subcategories
```

Now, in the form for a new article, I want a field for selecting a Category which will (with ajax) add another field for selecting the Subcategory. Well, the first problem is, how to select a Category when that model is not related to the Article model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have any special functionality in Subcategories, I'd recommend you to use self referencial association. Use something like [ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) gem. You'll have 2 models `Category` and `Article`

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_ancestry
  has_many :articles
end
```

It allows you to operate with your tree of categories in much more convinient way:

```
Category.roots                   Root nodes
Category.ancestors_of(node)      Ancestors of node, node can be either a record or an id 
Category.children_of(node)       Children of node, node can be either a record or an id
Category.descendants_of(node)    Descendants of node, node can be either a record or an id
Category.subtree_of(node)        Subtree of node, node can be either a record or an id
Category.siblings_of(node)       Siblings of node, node can be either a record or an id
```

In your form you can use Category.roots for preselect, and after one of them selected use Category.children_of(selected_node)

Comment: Totally interesting. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use [select_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-select_tag) helper instead of `f.select`

The value, then will not be a part of `params[:article]`

```
select_tag "category", options_from_collection_for_select(@categories, "id", "name")
```